# How to write a shell script to pick the excel sheet from particular path and mail it as attachment?

Tags: shell, unix

In the below case i'm  getting the mail but not attachment.
I have tried with the following script...

```
#!/bin/ksh

path ="users/Modeling/Analyst\ Folder/Piped"

echo "After path: $path"

cd $path

file =`ls -lrt | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3`

echo "File name found"

uuencode '$path/file' 'file'| mailx -s 'file' 'Billa21@outlook.com'

echo "File attached and mailed"
```

But this didn't work...

Im getting the output as :

```
pipeline.sh: path: not found
After path:
=:              cannot open: No such file or directory
dead.letter:    ascii text
File name found
$path/file: No such file or directory
File attached and mailed
```

But if I run the commands individually...
I'm getting the desired result..

Answer (score 0):

Please try using mailx with -a option for getting the file as an attachment in mail.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate quite clearly that this has nothing whatsoever to do with mailing an attachment. You could have abstracted `mailx` out of your question.

(Though, as an aside, [*manas* is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293403/560648) — you're using `mailx` wrong; read the documentation.)

The problem is that you do not correctly set the variable `path`; the interpreter's confusion regarding `=` indicates a syntax error on your part, and the message `$path/file: No such file or directory` shows that `$path` does not evaluate to anything at that point in the script.

```
  path ="users/Modeling/Analyst\ Folder/Piped"
#     ^
```

Remove this excess space.

Take more care and attention not to add random characters when you type.